# Graphics.DrawString with high resolution bitmaps == LARGE TEXT

Tags: vb.net, graphics, bitmap, gdi+

I have an app that creates a large bitmap and later the user can add some labels.  Everything works great as long as the base bitmap is the default 96x96 resolution.  If I bump it up to 300 for instance, then the text applied with Graphics.DrawString is much too large -  a petite size 8 or 10 font displays like it is 20.

On the one hand, it makes sense given the resolution increase, but on the other, you'd think the Fonts would scale. MeasureString returns a larger size when measured on a 300 vs 96 dpi bitmap, which wasn't really what I expected.

I've tried tricking it by creating a small bitmap of the appropriate size, printing to it, then pasting that to the master image.  But when pasted to the high res it enlarges the pasted image.

The only other thing I can think of is to create a high res temp bitmap, print to it, then shrink it before pasting to the main image.  That seems like a long way to go. Is there a compositing or overlay type setting that allows this?  Are font sizes only true for a 96 dpi canvas?

Thanks for any hints/advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The size of a font is expressed in inches.  One point is 1/72 inch.  So if you draw into a bitmap that has 300 dots-per-inch then your font is going to use a lot more dots for the requested number of inches.  So when you *display* it on a 300 dpi display then you'll get the size in inches back that you asked for.

Problem is, you are not displaying it a 300 dpi device, you are displaying it on a 96 dpi device.  So it looks much bigger.

Clearly you don't really want a 300 dpi bitmap.  Or you want to draw it three times smaller.  Take your pick.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a consistent size in pixels, specify UnitPixel when creating your Font object.